# Pandas to_latex - format table width at export or in overleaf

Tags: pandas, latex, overleaf

I'm exporting a pandss dataframe as tex file for my overleaf project, like so:

```
df.to_latex('df.tex')
```

when I import the file into my project:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\input{df}
\end{table}
```

[image]

It does not fit the page.

I  wonder if there's any way of formatting my width of font size or else as I export the file, or making it fit, after importing the file with `\input`.

I have tried using `\centering`, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the font size before you import the table, e.g.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\tiny % or whatever font size suites your needs
\input{df}
\end{table}
```

Alternatively you could give your numbers with a reasonable number of significant digits, this would surely safe tons of space.